# Analysis techiques for logical topologies

Tags: multilevel-analysis, spatial, topologies

I'm working in the area of analysis of logical computer systems (e.g https://goo.gl/images/KyLCCo). Specifically in the field of anomaly detection of these systems.

I was thinking about the field of spatial analysis where analysis is conducted on a topology over a physical space. I was wondering are the some comparable analysis techniques to analyse topologies there the area is not physical but rather logical.

If you look at the link to a sample diagram you can see that systems are at different levels (strata). Additionally the physical distance between the systems is not important but rather the categories are more important (e.g. Database Vs Middleware Vs HTTP/Presentation layer)

From the searching on Google-Scholar there isn't too much information to guide analysis techniques what is apparent is that using counts of categorical data may be appropriate.

I'm checking to see what suggestions folks may have for analysis of this type of data topology.

Comment: Maybe show us a diagram of your typical topology? Look into graph-theory based representations?